# convert a string to char for Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino-c++

**When I write**

String abc ="0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff";

const unsigned char displaydata[]={reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str())};

display.drawBitmap(displaydata, startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);

Get error: nvalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]

**When I write like this**

```
String abc ="0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff";

display.drawBitmap(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str()), startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);
```

No error but black screen no display image

**When I write like this**

```
const unsigned char displaydata={ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};

display.drawBitmap(displaydata, startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);
```

It is working

```c++
String abc ="0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff"

const unsigned char displaydata={ '"+abc+"'};

display.drawBitmap(displaydata, startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);
```

This is not display but

```c++
const unsigned char displaydata={ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};

display.drawBitmap(displaydata, startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);
```

This is working and displayed

I need convert a string to const unsigned char with code

is it possible ?

The data coming from the server is returning to me as stirng, I am trying to reflect it on the screen.

So I'm trying to convert

Comment: What is `'"+abc+"'` supposed to be? Don't you get a compiler warning there?

Comment: `abc.c_str()`;  https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/

Comment: String abc and displaydata are not even assigned the same data.

Answer (score 0):

- `'"+abc+"'` is an illegal character literal. You can't build an array like that.
- What looks like an array in your second example

  ```
  const unsigned char displaydata={ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
  ```

  is in fact only **one** `const unsigned char`. It should be:

  ```
  const unsigned char displaydata[]={ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
  ```

You can probably define your `String` like this:

```
String abc = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff";
```

Note that the encoding above matches your second example:
`const unsigned char displaydata[] = { 0xff, 0xff, ..., 0xff }` - not what you originally had in your `String`.

`String` has a member function called [`c_str()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/) returning "*A pointer to the C-style version of the invoking String*":

```
display.drawBitmap(abc.c_str(), startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);
//                    ^^^^^^^^
```

If the compiler complains that `c_str()` returns the wrong type for `display.drawBitmap()`, you can cast:

```
display.drawBitmap(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str()),
                   startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);
```

Comment: const unsigned displaydata[]={reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str())};
// get error :  invalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]

display.drawBitmap(displaydata, startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);

when I write direct get just black screen

display.drawBitmap(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str()),
                   startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);

Comment: @Coder06 I'm not sure what you're asking, but that looks utterly wrong. `const unsigned displaydata[]` is an array of `unsigned int`

Comment: I write direct get just black screen
display.drawBitmap(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str()),
                   startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);

Comment: I need convert string to const unsigned char array

 const unsigned char displaydata[]={reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str())};

Comment: @Coder06 Please copy the code you tried into your question. I have a hard time reading code in the comments. Just click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69274720/edit) to edit your question.

Comment: When I export the value manually, there is no problem, but when I convert the value from the server, it gives an error.

Comment: @Coder06 What error message does it print?

Comment: I edit question and error screen
https://www.hizliresim.com/ir9z6wn

Comment: @Coder06 But.., that's not at all what I suggested in my answer

Comment: @Coder06 And the assignment you try to do: `const unsigned char displayData[] = { reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.str()) }` tries to assign a _pointer_ to a `const unsigned char`.

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/jo2ttwn    Give error :'class String' has no member named 'str'

Comment: @Coder06 Please read my answer again. I've never suggested that you should create a `String abc = ""0xff, 0xff, ..";` and I even made a remark about the change I suggested to `abc`. I also did not suggest that `String` has a member called `str`. Please read carefully.

Comment: I'm very new to C, so I don't know exactly what to write and I'm confusing you

Comment: Try to put my suggested changes in the program and see what happens

Comment: String abc = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff";  

You told me to replace 0 with "\" in your answer, will the problem be solved if I edit the string value like this?

Comment: @Coder06 I'm not sure but it has a **much** better chance of succeeding. Also do this afterwards `display.drawBitmap(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(abc.c_str()), startX, startY, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, GxEPD_WHITE);` Note that it was not only the `0` you should replace. There should not be any spaces or commas in the string either.

Comment: @Coder06 Did you have any progress when you tried my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`String abc ="0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff"`

There is no **String** in the default C (or C++) libs. However, as pointed out in the comments, **String** is provided for Arduino. The example relating to std::string is still relevant.

`std::string abc = "0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff"`

This will not work as you need the byte value 0xff, not the string "0xff"

You also need to consider the difference between char, signed char and unsigned char. All these are 1-byte each, the meaning is different. e.g, 0xFF - when it is treated as **signed char**, it is negative number; but it is 255 as **unsigned char**. For **char**, the representation is compiler-specific.

If you are dealing with binary data, its best to use **uint8_t** - this is the same as **unsigned char**. So, for image processing, use **uint8_t, uint16_t and uint32_t** - this will ensure better portability. Each byte, short and int are guaranteed to be 1-byte, 2-bytes and 4-bytes respectively, and you will avoid bugs due to the sign-bit.

Thus, you can use
`const uint8_t displaydata[]={ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};`

Comment: There is no `std::string` included in arduino-c++ unfortunately. One has to download ArduinoSTL for that - but that implementation of the standard library is so old that it doesn't even support move semantics so I've stopped recommending it. Arduino comes with its own string type, called `String`, which is the one OP is using.

Comment: Did not know that - in which case const uint8_t displaydata is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, OP already used an `unsigned char[]` and got that to work but OP:s mission right now is, in OP:s own words, "_I need convert a string to const unsigned char_".